# Saving foreign key on update in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4, foreign-keys

I have two tables: clients and payments.

From clients I call the new payment form like so:

```
<%= link_to "Add Payment", controller: 'payments', action: 'new', client_id: client.id %>
```

That works fine but when I try to update that payment, the client_id field is not being saved. 
In payments controller I have:

```
  def update
    @payment.client_id = @payment.client.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @payment.update(payment_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @payment, notice: 'Payment was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @payment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I thought this would work because in payments show action I call the client object with

```
@client = @payment.client
```

Any ideas why a similar call is not working in update?

EDIT

to avoid confusion, that first line is part of the following table:

```
<tbody>
    <% @clients.each do |client| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= client.company_name %></td>
        <td><%= client.owner %></td>
        <td><%= client.main_contact_name %></td>
        <td><%= client.phone %></td>
        <td>
          <ul id="options_list">
            <li><%= link_to "Add Payment", controller: 'payments', action: 'new', client_id: client.id %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "View/Manage Payments", controller: 'clients', action: 'show_payments', id: client %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "XML Document", controller: 'clients', action: 'show_sepa', id: client %></li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
          <ul id="options_list">
            <li><%= link_to 'Show', client %></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_client_path(client) %></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'Destroy', client, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></li>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

EDIT 2:

Requested code (payments form partial)

```
<%= form_for @payment do |f| %>
  <% if @payment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@payment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this payment from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @payment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

  <fieldset id="form">
    <span><legend>Fill In The Form Below</legend></span>

    <%= f.hidden_field('client_id', :value => params[:client_id]) %>

    <div id="field">
      <%= f.label :signup_fee %>
      <%= f.text_field :signup_fee %>
    </div>

    <div id="field">
      <%= f.label :monthly_fee %>
      <%= f.text_field :monthly_fee %>
    </div>

    <div id="field">
      <%= f.label :date_of_payment, 'Payment Start Date' %>
      <%= f.date_select(:date_of_payment, :order => [:year, :month, :day]) %>
    </div>

    <div id="field">
      <%= f.label :payment_reference %>
      <%= f.text_field :payment_reference %>
    </div>

    <div id="field">
      <%= f.label :remittance_information, 'Remittance Information (optional)' %>
      <%= f.text_field :remittance_information %>
    </div>

    <div id="field">
      <%= f.label :mandate_id, "Mandate ID" %>
      <%= f.text_field :mandate_id %>
    </div>

    <div id="field">
      <%= f.label :mandate_date_of_signature %>
      <%= f.date_select(:mandate_date_of_signature, :order => [:year, :month, :day]) %>
    </div>

    <div id="field">
      <%= f.label 'Type of Payment:' %>
      <%= f.label :is_recurring, 'Recurring' %> 
      <%= f.check_box :is_recurring %>
      <%= f.label :is_onceoff, 'Once Off' %>
      <%= f.check_box :is_onceoff %>
    </div>    

    <div id="field">
      <%= f.label :batch_booking %>
      <%= f.check_box :batch_booking %>
    </div>

  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

Comment: wait - what's the code on the edit payment page?

Comment: <h1>Editing payment</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Show', @payment %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', payments_path %>

Comment: can i get the form code i mean

Comment: Oh really? How do I get around this then? Because I don't really want to change from table to form.

Comment: Sorry, I'll add the form code to the question

Comment: there will already be a _form.html.erb partial in your payments views

Comment: Yeah I know. That's the form I was using to add/update payment. The full code for that partial is up now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46217/discussion-between-richard-jordan-and-sosimple)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(edited for additional informaiton)

```
<%= link_to "Add Payment", new_client_payment_path(client) %>
```

this will only work if you have your routes set up nested:

```
resources :clients do
  resources :payments
end
```

you should be able to delete this line - it's not helping you

```
@payment.client_id = @payment.client.id
```

Comment: It's part of a table. I've added the full code to the question.

Comment: if you just do new_client_payment_path(client) rails should take care of the rest... you have got your strong parameters payment_params permit! set up for all the right attributes correct?

Comment: let me know if it helps :-) if not we can brainstorm some more

Comment: I'm now getting undefined method new_client_payment_path for #<#<Class:0xb6f835c>:0xb6f7ccc>

Comment: so how are you setting ```@clients``` because that looks odd - you'd think that if ```@clients``` is a collection of clients then ```client``` should be one of them

Comment: oh wait - do you have payments nested inside clients in your routes - otherwise that new_client_payment_path(client) won't work

Comment: What do you mean by nested?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting client can't be blank when I try to update a payment after saving it. Could this be an underlying issue, something deeper than just the way I'm passing client to payments?

Comment: can you paste the ```@clients``` assignment code and the payment_params method code - or just paste the controller(s) where ```@clients``` is set and where payment_params is set in the payments controller

Comment: It's in the index view so @clients = Client.all

Comment: In payments controller:     def payment_params
      params.require(:payment).permit(:client_id, :signup_fee, :monthly_fee, :date_of_payment, :payment_reference,
        :remittance_information, :mandate_id, :mandate_date_of_signature, :batch_booking, :sequence_type, :is_recurring, :is_onceoff)
    end